Central Limit Theorem proof using PGFs verification
So, I did a bunch of informal things and I wanted to ask if I have gone wrong anywhere. I understand PGFs are defined only for discrete distributions but I tried generalizing like this for a normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$:
$PGF(X) = G(t) = E[t^X] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}t^xf(x)dx$
If I put $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{2\pi} * e^{-x^2/2}$
$E[t^X] = 1/\sqrt{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}t^x e^{-x^2/2}dx$
$E[t^X] = 1/\sqrt{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{(2ln(t)x -x^2)/2}dx$
$E[t^X] = 1/\sqrt{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{( -(x-ln(t))^2 + ln(t)^2)/2}dx$
$E[t^X] = e^{\ln^2(t)/2}/\sqrt{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{( -(x-\ln(t))^2)/2}dx$
$E[t^X] = e^{\ln^2(t)/2}/\sqrt{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{( -(x-\ln(t))^2)/2}dx$
$E[t^X] = e^{\ln^2(t)/2}$
Now looking at $X$ from a random distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ say it has a PGF = F
The distribution of $\lim_{n \to \infty} {1/\sqrt{n}}*{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}$ should appoach $N(0, 1)$.
I can show that the PGF of the above distribtuion is the same as the PGF of the normal distribution:
$G(t) = E[\lim_{n \to \infty} t^{{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}/\sqrt{n}}] = \lim_{n \to \infty} E^n[t^{X/\sqrt{n}}]$
$G(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (E[(t^{1/\sqrt{n}})^X])^n$
$G(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (F({t^{1/\sqrt{n}}}))^n$
$\ln(G(t)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n(\ln F({t^{1/\sqrt{n}}}))$
$= \lim_{n \to \infty} (\ln F({t^{1/\sqrt{n}}}))/(1/n)$
$y = 1/\sqrt{n}$
$\ln(G(t)) = \lim_{y \to 0} (\ln F({t^y}))/y^2$
L'Hopital applies since $F(1) = 1$
$\ln(G(t)) = \lim_{y \to 0} F'({t^y})t^y \ln(t)/(2yF(t^y))$
$F(t^y)$ will be 1
$\ln(G(t)) = ln(t)/2 \lim_{y \to 0} F'({t^y})t^y/(y)$
L'Hopital applies again since $F'(1) = E[X] = 0$
$\ln(G(t)) = ln(t)/2 \lim_{y \to 0} (F''({t^y})\ln(t)t^yt^y + F'(t^y)t^y\ln (t))/(1)$
$F''(1) = 1$ since $\sigma = 1$
$\ln(G(t)) = ln^2(t)/2$
$G(t) = e^{ln^2(t)/2}$
I can't quite see where I'm going wrong with this
